# Delete ActionLink with confirm dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I'm trying to implement a simple `ActionLink` that will delete records using ASP.NET MVC. This is what I have so far:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", 
                    "Delete", 
                    new { id = item.storyId, 
                          onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure?');" 
                        })%>
```

However, it doesn't show the confirm box. Clearly I'm missing something or I have incorrectly built the link. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Don't confuse `routeValues` with `htmlAttributes`. You probably want [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Delete", 
    "Delete", 
    new { id = item.storyId }, 
    new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this article?');" }) 
%>
```

Comment: Avoid deleting records upon GET request! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786070/why-should-you-delete-using-an-http-post-or-delete-rather-than-get

Comment: Poor implementation. Don't modify the server data on GET

Comment: surely it should be: new { id = item.storyId, onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this article?');" })

Comment: If we are not suppose to delete using get then how to via Action link using POST?

Comment: Call to $.Ajax if the confirm is YES ?

Answer (score 15):

those are routes you're passing in

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete",
    new { id = item.storyId }, 
    new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this article?');" })     %>
```

The overloaded method you're looking for is this one:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx

Answer (score 15):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete",
    new { id = item.storyId }, 
    new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this article?');" })     %>
```

The above code only works for Html.ActionLink.

For

> Ajax.ActionLink

use the following code:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "deleteMeeting", new { id = Model.eventID, subid = subItem.ID, fordate = forDate, forslot = forslot }, new AjaxOptions
                                            {
                                                Confirm = "Are you sure you wish to delete?",
                                                UpdateTargetId = "Appointments",
                                                HttpMethod = "Get",
                                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                LoadingElementId = "div_loading"
                                            }, new { @class = "DeleteApointmentsforevent" })%>
```

The 'Confirm' option specifies javascript confirm box.

Answer (score 5):

You can also customize the by passing the delete item along with the message. 
In my case using MVC and Razor, so I could do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", 
    "DeleteTag", new { id = t.IDTag }, 
    new { onclick = "return confirm('Do you really want to delete the tag " + @t.Tag + "?')" })
```

Comment: How would one localize that confirm message the easiest way?

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
<button> @Html.ActionLink(" ", "DeletePhoto", "PhotoAndVideo", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "modal-link1", @OnClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you to delete this Record?');" })</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using webgrid [you can found it here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/615776/WebGrid-in-ASP-NET-MVC), the action links could look like the following.

[image]

```
    grid.Column(header: "Action", format: (item) => new HtmlString(
                     Html.ActionLink(" ", "Details", new { Id = item.Id }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" }).ToString() + " | " +
                     Html.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", new { Id = item.Id }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-edit" }).ToString() + " | " +
                     Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new { Id = item.Id }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this property?');", @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" }).ToString()
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

With image and confirmation on delete, which works on mozilla firefox

```
<button> @Html.ActionLink(" ", "action", "controller", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "modal-link1", @OnClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you to delete this Record?');" })</button>
<style>
a.modal-link{ background: URL(../../../../Content/Images/Delete.png) no-repeat center;
            display: block;
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;

        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the same thing; a delete button on my Details view. I eventually realised I needed to post from that view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @style="margin-right:30px" })

            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');" />
        }
```

And, in the Controller:

```
 // this action deletes record - called from the Delete button on Details view
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(MainPlus mainPlus)
    {
        if (mainPlus != null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(PCALConn))
                {
                    var result = db.Execute("DELETE PCAL.Main WHERE Id = @Id", new { Id = mainPlus.Id });
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Calls");
            } etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Any click event before for update /edit/delete records message box alerts the user and if "Ok" proceed for the action else "cancel" remain unchanged. For this code no need to right separate java script code. it works for me

`<a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-ID="@Item.ArtistID" onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to remove this Artist?');">Delete</a>`

Answer (score 0):

[image] MVC5 with delete dialogue & glyphicon. May work previous versions.

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Action", "Controller", new { id = model.id }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash", @OnClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you to delete this Record?');" }).ToHtmlString()))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also try this for Html.ActionLink DeleteId

Comment: Can you explain this answer a little bit? Maybe provide a code snippet that demonstrates your suggestion or describe where in the the OP's code this should go?