# How to make confirm dialog box after button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

What I'm trying to do is make a confirm dialog box popup when I press to create an item in my view. From what I understand from reading other posts (correct me if I'm wrong) is by using jquery. I'm not very familiar with jquery/javascript so I'm doing my best to understand what I'm doing. The code i found online is this.

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="Create" name="Common" type="submit" value="Create" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Create").click(function (e) {
            // use whatever confirm box you want here
            if (!window.confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
```

How it is right now every time I press the button it fires my POST create method in my controller right away without showing a dialog box. Can someone explain me why that happens and how i can fix it. I have tried adding code where `//use whatever confirm box you want here` is written but I don't really know what I'm looking for or what it needs to be written there.

**Posts i have read**

[Where i got the above code from](https://forums.asp.net/t/2007323.aspx?How%20to%20create%20a%20jquery%20confirm%20box%20in%20MVC%204%20)

[Delete ActionLink with confirm dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682107/delete-actionlink-with-confirm-dialog)

[ASP.NET MVC ActionLink and post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048778/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-and-post-method)

Comment: Attach yourself to the form post event instead of the button click. It will be easier to reason about and should fix your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `<input type="button" />`. Then call `submit()` for the form.

```
<form method="post" id="sampleform">

    <input id="Create" name="Common" type="button" value="Create" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#Create").click(function (e) {
                if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                    console.log('Form is submitting');
                    $("#sampleform").submit();
                } else {
                    console.log('User clicked no.');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

If you use ASP.NET MVC, you might want to consider using [Html.BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_20) Html Helper.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "sampleform"}))
{
    <input id="Create" name="Common" type="button" value="Create" />
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
    ... Same as above
</script>
```

Comment: Im trying to see if i can get this to work. What currently is happening is. I can see the console.log when i Ok or Cancel the promp but it doesnt seem like my controller method is being called so i dont think the $("#sampleform").submit(); is being called for some reason so im trying to work that out.

Comment: I updated the answer. Pleas also make sure you do not have script error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

try by adding onclick

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="Create" name="Common" type="submit" value="Create" onclick="DeleteFunction()"/>
...
</form>

<script>
    function DeleteFunction() 
    {
        if(confirm('Are you sure?'))
             return true;
        } else {
             return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this and now i get the confirm pop-up but doesnt matter if i press Ok or Cancel it always fires my controller post method

Comment: then try inline JavaScript confirm 

`<form id="Create" name="Common" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">`

Comment: Doesnt work now im getting the same problem as before where the confirm promp doesnt even show and my controller method gets called instantly

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work fine.  I use the on method but click method should have the same effect.  You don't need to specify window.confirm, just confirm will work for this too.

```
$("#Create").on("click", function (e) {
   // use whatever confirm box you want here
   if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Make sure that:

- Run this in the console and see of it returns 1: `$("#Create").length`  If it doesn't return 1, that is a problem
- Make sure there are no other JS errors, or that there is no malformed tags on the page.

Comment: It returns 1 when i run the code in console. So i dont know what i had done wrong. What Win commented worked so im going to use that for the moment. Will try to see if i can find what i did wrong later for learning purposes. Thank you very much for the comment thought.