# What is the Asp.Net Core TagHelper equivalent of Html.ActionLink with script

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I want to prompt a confirmation dialog before deleting. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4682135/6296435) answer here that works great

```
@Html.ActionLink(
          "Delete",
          "Delete",
          new { id = post.OriginalPost.ID },
          new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this post?');" });
```

but as I understand in Core one should avoid the use of ActionLinks. So are there any tag-helpers or different ways to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would normally use the `AnchorTagHelper`:

```
<a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@post.OriginalPost.ID" 
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this post?');">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Simplistically, tag helpers just rewrite HTML. For something like an anchor tag, Razor is looking for an attribute like `asp-action` to feed it through the tag helper, which ends up returning the same tag with meaningful changes/additions, such as adding in the `href` attribute with the correct URL. Other attributes just come along for the ride, so if you add something like `onclick` to the tag helper, you'll end up with that same `onclick` on the actual rendered anchor tag.