# html - how to give a submit button a variable for GET?

Tags: php, html, forms, get

i have the following button:

```
<form method="GET" action="/cms/deleteBlog/">
    <input class="btn btn-danger btn-small" type="submit" name="'.$blogID.'" value="Delete">
</form>
```

So right now i get the following url:

```
cms/deleteBlog/?1=Delete
```

obviously i want something like the following:

```
cms/deleteBlog/id=1
```

So i tried the following (which is obviously not working):

```
name="id='.$blogID.'"
```

So how do i solve this? i've been looking around on the internet, and i know the solution is quite easy. But i just can't remember the way how it is done!

Comment: You need to use .htaccess for rewriting urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a hidden input field, e.g:

```
<form method="GET" action="/cms/deleteBlog/">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$blogID.'">
    <input class="btn btn-danger btn-small" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Or, if you want pretty URLs:

```
<form method="GET" action="/cms/deleteBlog/id='.$blogID.'">
    <input class="btn btn-danger btn-small" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Comment: This worked for me! Will make use of hidden input fields from now on! thx.

Answer (score 3):

Add a hidden form field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
```

Also, you should **never** use `GET` to delete or modify data. Read [Why should you delete using an HTTP POST or DELETE, rather than GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786070/why-should-you-delete-using-an-http-post-or-delete-rather-than-get) for insight.

Comment: what I'm trying to do here is to parse the blogID. then on the cms/deleteBlog/ check for the ID, and write a query to delete the record that matches the ID.

Comment: @KevinvHengst this will get you the proper query string. please read that other post.