# CodeIgniter delete row from database

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to delete data from my database

Here's my code:

VIEW

```
<table border="1" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Nama Depan</th>
        <th>Nama Belakang</th>
        <th>TTL</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Keterangan</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($dataMember as $result) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo ($i+1); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['namaDepan'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['namaBelakang']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['TTL']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['email']; ?></td>
        <td>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() . "BelajarBerhadiah/hapusMember/" . $result->email; ?>"><button>Delete</button></a>  
        </td>
        
    </tr>
    <?php $i++; } ?> 
</table>
```

MODEL

```
public function Hapusdata($id){
    $this->db->where('email', $id);
    $this->db->delete('daftar');
}
```

Controller

```
public function hapusMember()
    {           
        $this->load->model('Member'); 
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->Member->Hapusdata($id);
        redirect (site_url('Belajarberhadiah/halaman_admin'));
    }
```

and the problem is i get

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/halaman_dMember.php
>
> Line Number: 105

What should i do?

Comment: FYI: Your code has a significant security vulnerability if it can work this way. This would mean your code has a delete link that can be activated via a HTTP GET request: [this means web trawlers can activate it and delete your stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/q/786070/254830), or I can send you an email with `<img src="http://example.com/BelajarBerhadiah/hapusMember/?id=1">` in it. (If your email client tries to retrieve that image, it activates that link and deletes that user.) Your modification actions should always rely on POST and other non-GET HTTP request types.

Comment: thank you sir for that information.... i really know nothing about that stuff,, i just try suggestion from my friend... the real thing is i just want to delete user from my database use CI, im so new in this CI thing so i search from any source but i cant found any answer :( @doppelgreener

Comment: Since you're getting into web development, you'd better learn about HTTP requests - they're pretty important! [Here's a tutorial that seems to cover the HTTP protocol decently.](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-the-protocol-every-web-developer-must-know-part-1--net-31177)

Comment: Thanks yous sirr its really helpful for me i will learn that @doppelgreener

Comment: You need to provide the code for the controller which loads your view. The code you provided for controller is the code works when the link in view has been clicked.

Comment: ohhh i see ^^
i try it and its work,, i didnt see that  
btw thanks @kishor10d

Comment: deleting with email is not good practice

Answer (score 1):

Please write href for delete tag as below:

```html
<a href ="<?php echo site_url('BelajarBerhadiah/hapusMember/1');?>">delete</a>
```

Also be sure that the column[email] you have used for where condition in controller is the correct one. Because column name is "email" in where condition and you are passing an integer value.