# c# webapi - The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have two simple routing methods:

## main routing directive:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/accounts")]
```

## first one

```
[Route("user/{id:guid}", Name = "GetUserById")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUser(string Id)
```

## second one

```
[Route("user/del/{id:guid}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteUser(string id)
```

I wonder why if I test the first method with direct ulr ( GET ) it works:

```
http://localhost/ReportApp_WebApi/api/accounts/user/1533882b-e1fd-4b52-aeed-4799edbbcda6
```

And if I try the second link that is just a little different:

```
http://localhost/ReportApp_WebApi/api/accounts/user/del/1533882b-e1fd-4b52-aeed-4799edbbcda6
```

I get: **The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.**

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second link is not just a little different. In fact it is pointing to the route that you have defined for your delete method. This method expects DELETE Http verb.

When you write the url directly on the browser it performs a GET request. If you want your delete method to work with a GET verb you have to put the attribte

```
[HttpGet]
```

before or just after your Route atttribute. **Although this I would not recommend to do it**. You can have a HTTP client like Fiddler or Postman to test this

Web Api uses conventions when naming methods in your controllers. Because you named your method DeleteUser, Web Api expects Delete verb.

EDIT>>>Please follow recommendations listed in comments. I have also make bold the part where I **do not recommend this**

Comment: I solved it by adding HTTPGET but I don't understand why it is now working... Its because the Route contains 'del' string and mvc do some checks on the route urls ?

Comment: yes, and so it is mapping to [Route("user/del/{id:guid}")]. Web Api uses conventions when naming methods in your controllers. Because you named your method DeleteUser, Web Api expects Delete verb.

Comment: Thanks! thats why! can you integrate with this info the solution?
I will mark as solved ass soon as I can

Comment: I have just completed with latest info the answer. Best regards

Comment: Though the answer is definitely correct, I strongly suggest you to **not** use `GET` method for actions with side-effects like a deletion. [More info here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/786074/3670737).

Comment: @DarioN Federuico is exactly right.  anyone who browses that url with a correct user id will delete users.  You definitely don't want a GET.  At the least make it a POST