# Delete method from routing works only via Postman, not browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I have implemeted simple routing:

```
    return RouterFunctions
            .nest(path("/api/person"),
                    route(GET("/"), personService::findAllPeople)
                            .andRoute(GET("/{id}"), personService::findOnePerson)
                            .andRoute(POST("/add"), personService::addPerson)
                            .andRoute(DELETE("/delete/{id}"), personService::deletePerson)
                            .andRoute(PUT("/update"), personService::updatePerson));
```

The most interesting method is `DELETE` becuase it only works via `Postman`. When I try to type `/api/person/delete/1` in browser it throws `404` with none errors in console - does anyone know why? In Postman I disabled all headers which are sent and still Postman works, browser not.

Comment: "...try to type /api/person/delete/1..." where are you typing this?

Comment: I type it in the url input in browser

Comment: That's not going to work; your browser is going to send the request using the GET verb, not DELETE.  Since you have no matching GET route, it returns 404.  You really, really do not want something to be deleted via a GET request regardless.

Comment: So generally I will not be able to do it via browser? Or should I create new route instead of andRoute to configure delete method?

Comment: Browsers only support GET and POST methods. When you type in the URL of the browser, it is GET. When it is a form, it is POST. There is some technique in some web frameworks called *method spoofing*, it is "marking" the method manually as PUT, DELETE, or PATCH, while really and technically it is POST.

Comment: You need to send a DELETE request via javascript/ajax or whatever else is consuming your API.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/786074/123422 for reasons why.

Comment: On the browser you can't directly. But you can do it using AJAX requests. Open your GET URL. Open the JavaScript console on your browser. Then initiate an AJAX request to your other methods. But you will need jQuery (without jQuery, it is a lot of code)

Comment: A browser can only send a GET request and since GET to be idempotent hence if  Fired from the browser it won't change the resource state on the server.

Comment: @PaulAbbott could you make this comment an answer for this? Reading questions that are answered in the comments really is a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

As @PaulAbbot said, entering an URL in your browser's address bar will issue a GET request only.

If you wish to send DELETE requests from your browser, you should use JavaScript to do so.