# Html.ActionLink onclick method equivalent for Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am currently using Url.Action for buttons on my dashboard and I would keep this consistent UI.

#### I have a delete button which I now want to implement a pop up box for to avoid mistake deletes.

I have achieved this using Html.Action link but I quickly learnt that I cannot put this inside an  tag. Can someone please aid me in making the equivalent to end up with a button? Thanks.

#### Url.Action Code

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Action","Controller", new {refNumber = item.RefNumber, null}'"/>
```

#### Html.ActionLink Code

```
@Html.ActionLink("Action","Controller", new {refNumber = item.RefNumber}, new {onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"})
```

Comment: `Url.Action()` is exactly what you need.

Comment: Yeah but I said I need to need to implement a pop up which the html.actionlink does and not url.action

Comment: Don't use Html.ActionLink for this, use Url.Action inside an input type=button. Better yet, make your Delete Action a POST, deletes and GET's dont do well.

Comment: thanks, but that does not answer my question, I just want a pop-up, the application works perfectly fine. I cannot use new {onclick="return confirm} inside Url.Action 4th parameter, else I would not leave it null.

Comment: A Delete action is altering data - it needs to be a POST method, not a GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action","Controller", new {refNumber = item.RefNumber, null})" onclick="return confirm('are you sure?');">Delete</a>
```

As mentioned in the comments, I'd highly recommend changing your action to a POST. Can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786070/why-should-you-delete-using-an-http-post-or-delete-rather-than-get).

Comment: thanks so much! I embedded an input tag inside the <a></a> and I now have it functioning like a button! and yeah thanks I will definitely read into it, I'm still just a junior developer so I will take every tip I can get! gracias!