# How to make asp-action tag helper do http delete?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to make asp-action tag helper do http delete?

At the moment i have following code which doesn't work

```
<a class="btn" asp-action="Delete" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-accountKey="@Model.Item1.AccountKey" method="delete">Delete</a>
```

Controller

```
[HttpDelete]
public void Delete(string accountKey)
{

}
```

Without `[HttpDelete]` it enters the action method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue with the ASP.NET Core MVC `asp-action` Tag Helper - the problem is down to the fact that `delete` is not a supported `method` in HTML forms (see the `method` section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Attributes)).

Although different browsers may handle it differently, Chrome just issues a `GET` request when it sees `delete` as the HTML form's method. When you remove `[HttpDelete]` from your `Delete` action, it defaults to `GET` (it's as though you'd added `[HttpGet]`), which is why the `GET` verb being used by Chrome now hits your `Delete` action.

In order to fix this, I suggest using the `POST` verb, which can be triggered using a `method` of `post` in your form and adding `[HttpPost]` to your delete action. Here's what it looks like:

HTML

```html
<a
    class="btn"
    asp-action="Delete"
    asp-controller="Home"
    asp-route-accountKey="@Model.Item1.AccountKey"
    method="post">Delete</a>
```

C#

```
[HttpPost]
public void Delete(string accountKey) { }
```

Using `post` is preferred over using `get` for reasons cited by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/786074/2630078).