# when I try to delete object I get "list out of index range" error

Tags: python, django, list, orm

this is my delete_category function :

```
def delete_category(request, id):
    user = request.user
    category = Category.objects.get(pk=id)
    category.user.remove(user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('auth_profile', args=[user.username]))
```

this is my category_detail function:

```
def category_detail(request, category_name):
    user = request.user
    category = Category.objects.filter(name=category_name, user__username=user)[0]
    return render_to_response("category_detail.html", { "category":category}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

this is category_detail.html:

```
        <p>{{category.name}}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'delete_category' category.id %}">delete</a>
```

If I have more than one category, I can delete when I click the delete link. But if I have only one category, I get this error:

`list index out of range`

Comment: where did you put the delete_category function?

Comment: For your future sanity's sake, don't allow `GET` requests to modify your database! That way lies terrible, terrible side effects. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705782/why-shouldnt-data-be-modified-on-an-http-get-request . That said, how are you linking to your `category_detail` view? Also, can you doublecheck your posted code? As it stands your view function takes a parameter `shelf_name`, but references an undeclared variable `category_name`. Assuming that's not an actual error, that view will throw that exception if the user and category_name pair don't match an object.

Comment: thanks a lot I will be more careful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
category = Category.objects.filter(name=category_name, user__username=user)[0]
```

by

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(name=category_name, user__username=user)
category = None
if categories:
   category = categories[0]
```

see also how to work properly with QuerySet objects [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/)

Answer (score 1):

your code is a little hard to follow, i suspect this is not the *exact* code, but that's ok.

list index out of range is referring to the `...[0]` you specified.

you may want to rewrite what you've got to better handle zero categories, but a quick fix is:

```
try:
    category = Category.objects.filter(name=category_name, user__username=user)[0]
except:
    category = None
...
```

Comment: and now I get Reverse for 'delete_category' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. Im confused.

Comment: this is crazy because if I have more than one category I can delete but if I have only one category I got error.

Comment: you need to rewrite your code to better handle the case where you have one or zero categories

Comment: with no category passed in you get `{% url 'delete_category' %}`...you should write an if statement in the templating language...

Comment: while I am on A category_detail_page if I try to delete this page I got error.

Comment: I not recommend use a try ... except block for do this. That line of code may fail for any other reason, not only "list index out of range"