# Convert curl command with --form-string to a URL

Tags: url, curl, reload

I have command (line-breaks added between command-line parameters for readability):

```
curl
    -s
    --form-string "token=AppToken"
    --form-string "user=UserToken"
    --form-string "message=Msg"
    --form-string "title=Title" 
    https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json
```

Can you tell me if this command can be converted into a URL link?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about converting a command line to a URL.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you tell me if this command can be converted into a url link?

**It cannot**.

- That `curl` command is for a `POST` with an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request body.
- "Links" are **always** `GET` requests and never for `POST` requests.

  - `<a href="#">` links in HTML and the web can only make `GET` requests without a request-body (at least, not without custom JavaScript interception).
  - In desktop software frameworks and toolkits (that have built-in Hyperlink widgets), I find (in my personal experience) that they're similarly designed around the assumption they'll be used to open a URL to a web-page and so pass the URL to the user's default browser, which will only make a `GET` request.
  - This is because following a link (i.e. executing a `GET` request) [must always be "safe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705782/why-shouldnt-data-be-modified-on-an-http-get-request) (i.e. `GET` requests *should not* mutate resource state).
- Additionally, "Links" cannot have a request body.

  - Though while `GET` requests [*can* (technically) have a request-body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET), support for that is not widespread; and obviously single URIs for hyperlink `GET` requests don't have any request-body data associated with them.

    - <sub>`GET` request bodies are intended to allow user-agents to make `GET` requests with associated request/query data that is too long to fit into the querystring of the URI (due to the common 1024 or 2048 char limit).</sub>

Comment: Many URLs support both `GET` and `POST`, it seems like it would be worth trying it as a `GET` request.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Whether or not you _can_ make a `POST` request to a URI from a custom client or JS code or HTML `<form>` is irrelevant to the fact that a hyperlink ("link" in the OP's parlance) can only initiate bodyless `GET` requests.